# AULab doesn't list AUSampler as an Audio Unit Instrument

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I am trying to use Core Audio's AUSampler in my iOS application.  Apple's [Technical Note TN2283](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2283/_index.html) and WWDC 2011 Session #411 mention using AULab to create an `aupreset` file with my desired audio samples, which I can then load in my iOS app.

Sadly, when I follow the instructions and try to add AUSampler in AULab, I don't see it as an option.  Only DLSMusicDevice appears.

How can I use AUSampler in AULab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of AULab (2.3, published in the October 2013 Audio Tools) is set to run as a 32-bit application.

The version of AUSampler that ships with OS X 10.9 appears to be 64-bit only.

In Finder, select AULab and Get Info.  Then uncheck "Open in 32-bit mode".

Try following the steps from the Technical Note / WWDC session, and AUSampler will appear as an Audio Unit Instrument.